tikz & amsmath: how can I align math formulas within a tikz matrix?
I have a TikZ matrix, and within each node, I have a set of math equations. Using align*, the alignment is off and shows, compared to the usual behavior, some extra spacing to the left of the &. How can this be fixed?
Additional question: can the text width command adapted in a way that it is just the width of the block of formulas?
The MWE shows the typical align* on top and then the TikZ that ought to be fixed. Other blocks of the matrix are left out to reduce complexity.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

It should look like this:
\begin{align*}
x, y &>0\\
x&\geq \gamma  \\
x' = y'&= 0
\end{align*}

But it looks like this:
\begin{tikzpicture}
    [auto,
    block/.style ={rectangle, draw, thick,
                    text width=7em, align=center, rounded corners,
                    minimum height=4em}]
    \matrix [column sep=18mm, row sep=15mm]
{
    % row 1
    \node [block]  (init)   {\texttt{init}
                    \begin{align*}
                    x, y &>0\\
                    x&\geq \gamma  \\
                    x' = y' &= 0        
                    \end{align*}
                    }; 
                    &  \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Use the aligned or the alignedat environment inside math mode to not have to deal with text width.

You don't have to guess the widths if you use aligned (and also gathered in order to get good spacing). Since you want to use & inside a node, you must replace the alignment symbol for the TikZ matrix.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
x, y &>0\\
x&\geq \gamma  \\
x' = y'&= 0
\end{align*}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  auto,
  block/.style ={
    rectangle,
    draw,
    thick,
    text width=7em,
    align=center,
    rounded corners,
    minimum height=4em
  },
]
  \matrix [ampersand replacement=\&] {
    % row 1
    \node [block] (init) {
      $\begin{gathered}
        \texttt{init} \\
        \begin{aligned}
          x, y &>0 \\
          x&\geq \gamma  \\
          x' = y' &= 0        
        \end{aligned}
      \end{gathered}$
    };
   \& \\
  };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}



Thanks @egreg, this even helps with the bonus question. Very helpful!

You should some how distinguish ampersands belonging to align* environment from ampersands belonging to matrix:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
It should look like this:
\begin{align*}
x, y    & >0            \\
x       &\geq \gamma    \\
x' = y' &= 0
\end{align*}

However now looks like this:

    \begin{tikzpicture}[
block/.style = {draw, thick, rounded corners, 
                text width=7em, align=center, minimum height=4em}]
\matrix [column sep=18mm, row sep=15mm,
         ampersand replacement=\&]  % <---
{
    % row 1
\node [block]  (init)   {\texttt{init}
                \begin{align*}
                x, y    & >0            \\
                x       & \geq \gamma   \\
                x' = y' & = 0        
                \end{align*}
                }; 
                    \&  \\          % <---
};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Wow, this is very elegant. I would have never imagined that an ampersand would be the source of the issue. Thank you, @zarko!

@freshens, sometimes help to read package documentation . But documentation is huge and it is easy overlooked some details ... See TikZ and PGF manual, section 20.5 Considerations Concerning Active Characters, page 327.

Yes, yes. I did before I posted - but that documentation is just k***ing me. Especially, if I do not know, what exactly I am looking for ;-) Ampersand would have been my final guess.
